# Facebook Instant Articles: not every news appear on Production Articles list

Tags: facebook, drupal, facebook-instant-articles

I have submitted a request for the Instant Articles, and it's been approved. Now we have another problem, on Production Articles list (Facebook settings), I cannot see all the articles from our website, but most of them are there. Also, some newly added articles appeared there, and after some time they were gone somehow. My production rss feed contains all the articles from the website.

My website is running on Drupal.

Maybe the problem is because there are really too many articles on the website, and so not all of them can be displayed there? I really have no idea.

Did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: The articles are showing up in your RSS feed, but not on the webpage? Are you using a View?

Comment: Yes, the articles are showing up in my RSS feed, all of them, but not all of them are showing up on the Production List, on the settings of my Facebook page (most of them are). I am using a view - Facebook Instant Articles (content).